# How to encode pdf file in base64 format?

Tags: php, pdf, base64

> I have done in this way. Is it correct?

```
    $filename = "../pdfs/reactjs_tutorial.pdf";
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');
    $contents = fread($handle,filesize($filename));
    fclose($handle);
    $encoded = chunk_split(base64_encode($contents));

/*This is how I have done*/
```

Comment: Other than running the file through a Base-64 encoder and sending the result?

Comment: I have saved in database its url but as per api requirement I need to encode the pdf file itself in base 64 format.

Comment: I need to send the pdf file in the encoded format

Comment: Have you tried googling `base64 encode pdf file`, you'll find thousands of helpful tools and guides.

Comment: @ MCMXCII Yes I tried searching but I am unable to make out how to use it. So I need some help in it.

Comment: Its not hard `base64_encode(file_get_contents('/path/to/file.pdf'));`

Comment: I have encoded the pdf as shown in the above code. Now I want to know how shall I store this encoded pdf in database server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      $query1 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT  `offer_id` ,  `offer_img_url` ,  `terms` FROM  `offers` LEFT JOIN system ON system.shop_id = offers.shop_id LEFT JOIN bill ON bill.sys_id = system.sys_id WHERE yb_id =  '$yb_id' LIMIT 0 , 30 ");
  if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)>0)
      {
        $data4 = array();
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query1))
         {
        $data4['offer_id'] = $row['offer_id'];
        $data4['offer_img_url'] = base64_encode($row['offer_img_url']);
        $data4['terms'] = $row['terms'];
         $data2[] = $data4;
      }
```